# SQL select row with max date from table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create a query where I get the row with the most recent time stamped date. I know `MAX` cant be used in a `WHERE` clause but I would need something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE MAX(timestamp)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want only one row, use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select d.*
from data d
order by d.timestamp desc
limit 1;
```

If you want all such rows in the case of a tie, then you can use:

```
select d.*
from data d
where d.timestamp = (select max(d2.timestamp) from data d2);
```

Comment: Thank you the first one is exactly what I needed! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `MAX` function cannot be used in `WHERE` clause because it is an aggregate function that is used with grouping. However, it can be used in `HAVING` clause which you can consider to be the grouping equivalent to `WHERE`.

So for example, this is valid:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
GROUP BY name
HAVING MAX(amount) < 1000
```

This is just an example, and obviously does not do what you want. Gordon's answer is what you need, but I just wanted to answer your question about using aggregate functions like `MAX` in a condition.